# How to stop wordpress mangling R syntax '<-'?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I have a self-hosted WP install, and have been using codecolorer (and have tried a few others along the way) to highlight R syntax. Looks nice, too.

The problem is that R uses a `<-` symbol instead of `=` when assigning objects (on pretty much every single line), and when you switch from 'Visual' to 'HTML' while editing a post it will mangle the code - `<-` becomes `&lt;-`; worse, sections of the code will disappear.

It would be possible to use `=` for the 'assign' command but it's not, strictly-speaking, correct. At the moment I have to do all the pretty writing and inserting of images in WYSIWYG 'visual' mode, then switch to HTML just before I post to fix up the R code, and then be careful *never* to switch back again. Ever.

Any fixes for this behaviour?

EDIT: examples!
Putting this into the Visual editor:

```
[cc]
lorum <- ipsum
[/cc]
```

Produces the following in the *final post*:

```
lorum &lt;- ipsum
```

Going back to HTML mode and putting a `<-` code worked *for the final post* but then I could never switch back to Visual without the `<` being interpreted as part of a tag.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping those chunks in `<code></code>`?

Comment: Yep - they're all wrapped nicely. <code lang="rsplus"></code>.

Comment: I found some sample R code and pasted it into the WP editor. I switched back and forth between Visual and HTML mode with no ill effects. The transliteration of '<' into '&lt;' is supposed to happen. The '<' character has special meaning as a start-of-tag in HTML, so it must be escaped into the '&lt;' entity to show up correctly in text. Were you by chance changing it back to a '<' while in HTML mode? Because that would wreak havoc on your post.

Comment: The only way to make '&lt' not appear in the *post* within the code was to put it in while in HTML mode - try 'preview' to see what I mean. Indeed, that's why it gets mangled twixt Visual and HTML ...

Comment: Okay, you've edited with more details... When you switch to HTML editor, DO NOT change '&lt;' back to '<'. This is what is causing your problems. Leave it alone. It's doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @DougalCampbell - except that leaving it as &lt *keeps it as &lt in the published post*, which is not at all correct. Works as long as one doesn't switch back to Visual (which re-parses the text looking for tags). However, see solution below!

Comment: I know it's been a couple of months, but I just wanted to point out that this must have been a side-effect of CodeColorer (or perhaps some other plugin). As I said previously, I was able to past R code containing the <- operator into the editor, switch back and forth between Visual and HTML mode, and everything worked fine, in a stock WordPress install.

Comment: Did it look fine even after publishing the post?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. A real RTFM moment.

The FAQ for CodeColorer  makes a note about this (though it's not mentioned in the main how-to text).

Using the `escaped = "true"` code in the `[cc]` tag brings back the behaviour I was looking for – now it's possible to write the `<-` operator in Visual (and it becomes `&lt` in HTML), but the published post displays `<-` correctly.

Thus, entering this in the visual editor:

```
[cc escaped="true"]
lorum <- ipsum
[/cc]
```

Produces, in the published post:

```
lorum <- ipsum
```